# How do I stop Music from playing with my stop button?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am creating two buttons, using Corona SDK, one for playing music and the other for stopping. The program works fine up until i create the stop button and nothing works. There is no audio. Can someone help me resolve this please?

```
          local widget = require("widget")
          display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

            centerX = display.contentWidth * .5
            centerY = display.contentHeight * .5

   -- Background
   local bg = display.newImageRect("bg_iPhone.png", 1100, 3200)
   bg.x = centerX
   bg.y = centerY

   local isAudioOn = true

   local soundJump = audio.loadSound("boing.mp3") --[[loadSound is for animations]]--
   local soundMusic = audio.loadStream("HappyPants.wav") --[[loadStream is for background music]]--

 --Sound function to play music
   local function playSound()
     if isAudioOn then
       audio.play(soundMusic)
       print("Boing!")
     end
   end

 -- Button Function that controls what happens after button is pressed
   local function buttonHit(action)
     if action == "play" then
       playSound()
     elseif action == "stop" then
       audio.stop(playSound)
     end
   end

 -- Play Button
   local playButton = widget.newButton{
   label = "Play",
   id = "play",
   x = 330,
   y = 500,
   labelColor = { default={ 0, 19, 189 }, over={ 0, 19, 189, 1 } },
   onPress = buttonHit
   }

  -- Stop Button
   local stopButton = widget.newButton{
   label = "Stop",
   id = "stop",
   x = 330,
   y= 550,
   labelColor = { default={ 0, 19, 189 }, over={ 0, 19, 189, 1 } },
   onPress = buttonHit
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **buttonHit** function is wrong.

You pass in the argument **action**, however, since you are using widget library, the only thing that gets passed into the function is **event**. Also, you've given the buttons an **id**, not an action. This id then belongs to the event target, i.e. the button that is being pressed.

What you want is something along the lines of:

```
local function buttonHit( event )
  if event.target.id == "play" then
    playSound()
  else
    audio.stop(playSound)
  end
end
```